# Jmeter - jmeter.save.SaveService: Conversion error com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException: -1 : -1

Tags: jmeter

I am having issue with Opening JMeter Test Plan, below is the exception i am getting. This started happening suddenly after system restart.

Error -

```
015/03/25 13:08:17 ERROR - jmeter.save.SaveService: Conversion error com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException: -1 : -1
---- Debugging information ----
message             : -1
cause-exception     : java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
cause-message       : -1
class               : org.apache.jmeter.testelement.property.DoubleProperty
required-type       : org.apache.jmeter.testelement.property.DoubleProperty
converter-type      : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.ReflectionConverter
path                : /jmeterTestPlan/hashTree/hashTree/hashTree[6]/hashTree[10]/hashTree/ConstantThroughputTimer/doubleProp/name
line number         : 1007
class[1]            : org.apache.jmeter.timers.ConstantThroughputTimer
converter-type[1]   : org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.TestElementConverter
class[2]            : org.apache.jorphan.collections.ListedHashTree
converter-type[2]   : org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.HashTreeConverter
```

Answer (score 0):

After spending hours i found workaround. Just simply run Jmeter as Administrator and it will work.